# AngularJS submit function not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm getting my first taste of AngularJS, having build quite a lot with laravel as a backend. So I installed laravel and created an `index.blade.php` file. In it I have a `ng-submit`, but I can't get it to work.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app>

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Laravel and AngularJS test</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-controller="TodoController">

            <h1>Todo</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Search todos" ng-model="search">

            <ul>

                <li ng-repeat="to in todos | filter:search">

                    @{{ todo.body }}

                </li>

            </ul>

            <form ng-submit="addTodo()">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Add a todo" ng-model="newTodo">
                <button type="submit">Add todo</button>

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function TodoController($scope) {

    $scope.todos = [

        { body: 'Groceries' },
        { body: 'Drive' }

    ];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {

        $window.alert('test');


    };

}
```

Comment: is there any console errors ?

Comment: None, would've been a lot easier if there were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95gyct1a/)

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
.controller('TodoController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.todos = [

        { body: 'Groceries' },
        { body: 'Drive' }

    ];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {

        $window.alert('test');


    };

}]);
```

With html like:

```
<div ng-app="todoApp">     
    <div ng-controller="TodoController">

        <h1>Todo</h1>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Search todos" ng-model="search">

        <ul>

            <li ng-repeat="to in todos | filter:search">

                @{{ to.body }}
            </li>

        </ul>

        <form ng-submit="addTodo()">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a todo" ng-model="newTodo"/>
            <button type="submit">Add todo</button>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your stuff, but then I get `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: `Failed to instantiate module todoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$injector/nomod?p0=todoApp`

Comment: Well, errors are progress!  Silly questions these I know, but is your main.js file definitely being loaded correctly?  Do you have just one ng-app declaration in your HTML?  Fine if it's on the html tag rather than in a div but make sure it's ng-app="todoApp" if you've copied the js line for line.

Comment: Yes, there's only one `ng-app` declaration and it's on the `<html>` tags now. However, my guess is that the `main.js` file isn't begin loaded properly, since it's Laravel.

Comment: Well, turns out it had something to do with the caching. I looked at the page code and saw that the first draft of `main.js` was being loaded. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
function TodoController($scope,$window) { .....
```

try to modify with this way :)

Comment: Yes, it is, that's the strange part. And the alert is just for testing, I want to add the text of the input to the list.

Comment: `<form ng-submit="addTodo(newTodo)"> .. `

Answer (score 0):

Controller should be define like following in main.js

```
angular.module('todoApp', []) .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

Give name to ng-app to ng-app='todoApp' in html tag